# How do I properly compute child data?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Given the following data structure, what is the most efficient way of getting the `level` for each `character` based on their `experience`? I know that I *could* store `level` with the other properties, but hoping there's a way to do this without doing so.

```
{
  "characters": {
    "-k1239748": {
      "name": "Ada",
      "experience": 0
    },
    "-k827493": {
      "name": "Beth",
      "experience": 2331
    },
    "-k344432": {
      "name": "Carol",
      "experience": 4789
    }
  },
  "levels": {
    "-k123433": {
      "level": 1
      "minimumExperience": 0
    },
    "-k412312": {
      "level": 2
      "minimumExperience": 2000
    },
    "-k113433": {
      "level": 3
      "minimumExperience": 4000
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output would be:

```
ada.level = 1
beth.level = 2
carol.level = 3
```

My assumption is that there's no easier way than:

- grabbing the list of `characters`
- grabbing the list of `levels` within the `complete` block
- iterating over each `character` and assigning the `character.level` property to whatever I get from some function I'd make called `getLevelForExperience(experience)`.

I find this to be kind of tedious and unnecessary, especially when coming from SQL where I could just do a `JOIN`, or have some computed properties in `C#` that could grab a value from a function only when needed, etc.

What I'm looking for is the syntax for doing something like the following:

```
this.af.database.list('/characters')
  .map(characterResult => {
    this.af.database.list('/levels').startAt(result.experience).first()
      .subscribe(levelResult => {
        result.level = levelResult;
      });

    return characterResult;
  });
```

I am using some pseudocode in the middle of the above block because I'm not sure what fits where, and regardless I don't know that this is the proper way of doing it, but I just can't wrap my head around the best way to get values like this efficiently without duplicating redundant data in my table on `set` or `update`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just load all the levels and select the correct one client-side.

I'd also consider storing the levels slightly differently, since the IDs seem like they'll just get in the way over time:

```
"levels": {
  "exp0": 1
  "exp2000": 2
  "exp4000": 3
}
```

You could even consider using an array here:

```
"levels": [0, 2000, 4000]
```

Although you'd have to offset the levels by one, or pad with an extra null there:

```
"levels": [null, 0, 2000, 4000]
```

Comment: In an example like the above, I've reduced some of the data, but the levels all have more data alongside it so reducing to an array won't work. Regardless, I'm specifically trying to figure out how that looks using AngularFire2 and/or the Observable pattern as a whole, using inner subscriptions/maps and all that. Not really schema structure. As in, imagine I had child data I needed to evaluate after pulling in every specific user and displaying it all alongside a list of users.